# Is there any way to make a constructor default values in a templated class?

Tags: c#, c++, templates

I know that in C# you can do:

```cs
class Account<T>
{
    T id = default(T);
}
```

which assigns to templated `id` value default value of data type. How can I do the same in C++?

Comment: [Member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Comment: do u mean constructor parameters default values and this parameter is of type `T`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class Account
{
    T id{};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make constructor default parameter, you can provide a constructor and do something like the following

```
template <class T>
class Account<T>
{
    T id;
    Account( T id = T{}) : id{ id } {}
};
```

but if you want to use the default constructor only (as in your provided code), use `T id{};` instead of `T id = default(T);`